# Ubuntu Services

Tags: 16.04, services

I am sorry if there's already a thread about this. I tried my best looking for the same ubuntu version but I only saw this:
[After modifying /etc/hosts which service needs to be restarted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665995/after-modifying-etc-hosts-which-service-needs-to-be-restarted)

We're using ubuntu 16.04.06.

Do I have to restart my services after some edit/config?

I'm sorry again if I only need a confirmation about my problem. Thank you for the help

Comment: I suggest you check you've applied all updates, 16.04.7 was released back in August 2020 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/), so a fully-upgraded 16.04 system should report itself as 16.04.7 (*the 13-August-2020 date is the ISO release date, an installed system usually reports 16.04.7 before that date when updates are applied*).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to restart anything after making changes. If the DNS is still cached somewhere then you may want to clear it. As far as I know, with normal operation, that's it.

To clear systemd-resolve's cache:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

If you want to verify that you cleared it out:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --statistics
```

It should read:

> Current Cache Size: 0

Comment: Will try this one, thank you for confirming.